# MongoDB - Fetch top 5 fields of a leaderboard

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, ejs

I have a very simple table which outputs the data as

```
{
_id: 55dbdffeaba8ee274d3b9f89,
    firstname: 'Jim',
    lastname: 'Kirk',
    email: 'ewrwe@kewoio.com',
    points: 3333,
}
```

I have about 10 records in my database so far.  I use the following var to create user model.

```
var User = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

I want to sort the points by the most and display the top 5 at any given time..store as a variable and pass through to express/ejs as an array.

So far I have this query but when I console.log I get undefined.

```
var leaderboard = User.find( {points: {$exists: true}} ).sort({points : -1}).limit(5);
```

Update: Upon running this query in Robomongo I get 5 records with all data, but a console.log returns the data 'undefined'.  How can I output data as array to put into a table and also filter out the _id and email?

Comment: Did you mean to type ".sort({score : -1})" it seems like 'score' should be 'points'

Comment: changed to points, also updated my findings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is after

```
var leaderboard = User.find( {points: {$exists: true}} ).sort({points : -1}).limit(5);
```

get's executed leaderboard contains a cursor. Append `.toArray()` to the end of the command and you should be good to go. Your final command should look like this:

```
var leaderboard = User.find( {points: {$exists: true}} ).sort({points : -1}).limit(5).toArray();
```

Check out [the documentation](http://docs.mongodb.org/master/reference/method/cursor.toArray/) for more information.

Comment: Cursor doesn't have a "toString()" method which is why it returns undefined. I'm pretty sure anyway.

Comment: Any reason why I would be getting 'User.find( {points: {$exists: true}} ).sort({points : -1}).limit(5).toArray();' is not a function? I'm testing this with the exact same code and created the User model with a database containing 10 records as well. I've been hunting for this solution for another project but I wanted to see it working.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you mess "points" and "score" document fields.

Comment: That was a mistake but having corrected I get undefined, even though in robomongo I get the 5 records.